# Adding data into a list while streaming another list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Let's say we have some entities, every entity has a list of searchable fields and a type. Is there a better (read more efficient way) to map those field in a list for every different type of entity.

Currently what I am doing is :

```
final Collection<IndexedField> indexedFields = new ArrayList<>();
for (String type : types) {
    final Class<? extends IndexedEntity> targetClass = indexedEntities.getClassByType(type);
    indexedFields.addAll(indexedEntities.getSearchFieldsFor(targetClass));
}
```

This works, but is there some better way to achieve this ? Maybe something with stream api.

Comment: In your question you say you want to map fields by type. In your code you are using one single list. Either you should use a Map<String, List<IndexedField>> (with the String key being the type), or I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you make this clearer so we can help you ?

Comment: Sorry, when I said map I ment stream api map function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
 types.stream()
     .map(indexedEntities::getClassByType)
     .flatmap(x -> indexedEntities.getSearchFieldsFor(x).stream())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten that to

```
types.stream().<Class<? extends IndexedEntity>>map(
            type -> indexedEntities.getClassByType(type)).<Collection<? extends IndexedField>>map(
            targetClass -> indexedEntities.getSearchFieldsFor(targetClass)).forEach(indexedFields::addAll);
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use `forEach` to populate other collection. Is it no thread safe and is it better to use `collect`

Answer (score 0):

You also can write by using only method references:

```
final Collection<IndexedField> indexedFields = types.stream()
                                       .map(indexedEntities::getClassByType)
                                       .map(indexedEntities::getSearchFieldsFor)
                                       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```